GStreamer tee stuck when trying to split and convert multiple RTP/H264 streams from a single pcap file
I receive RTP/h264 streams of 11 cameras via a single network interface and record them in a single pcap-file using tcpdump. Now I want to convert the single camera streams to videos. I know that I can use pcapparse together with the argument dst-port to convert each camera one-by-one, but my goal is to make the conversion much more efficient by converting all streams together using tee. However, my tee solution does not start the conversion and just stuck after invocation.
Working minimal example:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.pcap ! pcapparse dst-port=5001 ! "application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! avimux ! filesink location=video_5001.avi
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.pcap ! pcapparse dst-port=5002 ! "application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! avimux ! filesink location=video_5002.avi

Non-working minimal example which just stuck after invocation:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.pcap ! tee name=t \
    t. ! queue ! pcapparse dst-port=5001 ! "application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! avimux ! filesink location=video_5001.avi \
    t. ! queue ! pcapparse dst-port=5002 ! "application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! avimux ! filesink location=video_5002.avi


Increase the queue sizes. You probably fill one completely before the other one has a complete parseable unit.
